# How can I exclude the first row from a result query?

Tags: mysql, sql

Consider the following query-

```
SELECT * FROM GAME_LIST WHERE
  genre     = (SELECT Genre FROM GAME_LIST WHERE name='$searchTerm') OR
  publisher = (SELECT Publisher FROM GAME_LIST WHERE name='$searchTerm')
  ORDER BY CASE WHEN name LIKE '%$searchTerm%' then 1 else 2 end, points DESC
```

This query will generate number of rows from `GAME_LIST` table. For example-

```
A - 123 - W
B - 235 - R
C - 323 - R
D - 146 - R
E - 167 - W
F - 189 - W
G - 165 - R
```

But I don't want to include the first row (in this case `A - 123 - W`).
How can I achieve this within my existing query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `offset` capability of `limit`.  In MySQL, this would often be written as:

```
  ORDER BY CASE WHEN name LIKE '%$searchTerm%' then 1 else 2 end, points DESC
  LIMIT 1, 9999999
```

The second argument is just a big number to be sure you get all the rows you want.

This can also be written as:

```
LIMIT 99999999 OFFSET 1
```

The `OFFSET` counting starts at `0` for the first row, so `1` skips the first row, starting at the second.

Comment: Awesome! I'm a newbie in mysql and your explanation helps me to understand the fact. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

```
SELECT * FROM GAME_LIST WHERE
  genre     = (SELECT Genre FROM GAME_LIST WHERE name='$searchTerm') OR
  publisher = (SELECT Publisher FROM GAME_LIST WHERE name='$searchTerm')
  ORDER BY CASE WHEN name LIKE '%$searchTerm%' then 1 else 2 end, points DESC 
  LIMIT 2, (    SELECT * FROM GAME_LIST WHERE
     genre     = (SELECT Genre FROM GAME_LIST WHERE name='$searchTerm') OR
     publisher = (SELECT Publisher FROM GAME_LIST WHERE name='$searchTerm'))
```